# When can a 2-cocycle on a subgroup can be extended?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, cohomology, group-cohomology, schur-multipliers

This question is based on a question [when is the restriction $H^2(G,\mathbb{C}^*)\to H^2(K,\mathbb{C}^*)$ surjective?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/177678/when-is-the-restriction-h2g-mathbbc-to-h2k-mathbbc-surjective)
I am asking this as a new question as I already asked that user but got no response.

I wish to know what is that algorithm by which I can check that a 2-cocycle on $K$ is image of 2-cocycle on some some subgroup of $G$ under the restriction map.

Comment: You can do this in Magma (see [here](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/762)) in the case when the module is a finitely generated abelian group. That does not apply to ${\mathbb C}^*$ but I think you could still get the result by using a suitable finitely generated subgroup of ${\mathbb C}^*$ (you probably just need the $|G|$th roots of unity).